# Can android boot up without screen?

Tags: android, hardware, usb-otg

Im working on a project which I have to remove screen from my Samsung S5 with CM12(5.1) and connect with an OTG-Ethernet adapter.

with screen everything is fine. but after I removed screen away, it just wont boot up.

then I tried original rom of S5(5.0), it does boot up, but system does not support otg-ethernet anymore.

is there anyone can help me solve this or give me some hint?